# QtiPlot on Ubuntu 16.04 cannot find Python configuration files

Tags: python

I have `QtiPlot 0.9.8.9 svn 2288` installed on Ubuntu 16.04.

Last time I installed `pip` in order to manage Python packages. I also installed some Python packages. Since that I cannot select Python scripting language in QtiPlot - it says it cannot find Python configuration files `qtiplotrc.py` and `qtiUtil.py` alhtough they are both present in the given location `/usr/share/qtiplot`. How can I use Python within QtiPlot again?

I don't know where to seek help so I'm posting the question here.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtiplot/+bug/435918 that can be solved by changing the `qtiplotrc.py` file.